# Facebook FQL -- very slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$query = "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())";
$query = urlencode($query);
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. 'fql?q='.$query. '&access_token=' .    $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

This is the query. It works me faster because I have limited friends. But some app users say that it is very very slow for them if they have about 2000+ friends. They said it took 30 seconds to minutes too.

Why it is very slower? Is there any wrong in this request?

Comment: What if you try to perform query for 2000+ friends and see yourself? Everybody lies

Comment: just i tried that after posting here :) It is slow. I checked the execution time of the script at different level. It takes long time with facebook to get data? Could the server's networking or curl be slow? How to check that in taht case?

Comment: `SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (...)` - this part makes no sense. The whole query can be reduced to `SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()`

Comment: And it's easier to use built-in methods rather than manual `file_get_contents` http://stackoverflow.com/a/7827550/251311

Comment: Thanks. If you can post it as answer, I will close this

Comment: @zerkms can you post your comments as answer? It helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first thing - as long as you filter users by `uid` and only select `uid` after that - the outer query looks redundant. So the final query can be reduced to

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

The second thing: it is a bit more handy to use fb php sdk to perform FQL queries, not `file_get_contents`, like:

```
$facebook->api("/fql?q={$fql}");
```

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827550/251311)

Answer (score 1):

It is slower simply because there is more data to be collected.  2000+ friends is quite a lot for a single query...

Some helpful info can be found here - https://developers.facebook.com/live_status.

Other than the live status of the platform (indeed useful to know), there is also two graphs displaying the average API response time and the API error count.  If you are noticing extremely slow requests, head over to that link to see if maybe it is a system wide issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my view FQL is good but should be used when regular graph API can't fulfill your requirements. In the given case if the only requirement is to get IDs of friends then you can simply use following code.

```
FB.api("me/friends?fields=id&limit=3000", function(resp){//process data});
```

Comment: is it true? Is it faster method than fql?

Comment: @Kamini: I'm sure they are very close by performance. The storage used is the same, but only 2 different interfaces

Comment: In my experience with FQL you end up doing processing on your own. But Graph API can give you processed result. I may be wrong but that's my experience with FB API and FQL.